# How to simulate logging into a Google Account using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, cypress, google-2fa

I am trying to simulate logging into a Google Account but I am already having issues just loading the login page.

This is my code:

```
cy.origin('https://accounts.google.com', () => {
  cy.visit('/servicelogin')
})
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwS6A.jpg) is the error message that I am getting. I tried increasing the `pageLoadTimeOut` but it still won't work.

Note: I am using `cy.origin` because after a successful login on Google, I will be navigating to another domain for more testing.

Comment: I'm able to access the site with `cy.visit('accounts.google.com)`, but after inputting the username and clicking on the next button it shows an [error](https://imgur.com/Z8zePpJ) message, "RPC executor service threw an error!"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem "RPC executor service threw an error!" The problem was resolved when one of the cookie filters was disabled in the ad blocker. Namely, in my case, in the Adguard extension, I disabled - Self-destruction of the main cookies. In the Anti-tracking section. The problem was both in the Google Chrome browser and in the Microsoft Edge browser.